Fehling's Solution + Aldehyde(which is oxidised)
When Fehling's solution oxidizes aldehydes, $\ce{CuO}$ (orange-red) is formed characterizing the presence of an aldehyde which is oxidized into carboxylic acid. Now since $\ce{CuO}$ is formed, $\ce{Cu^2+}$ also appears to be oxidized? When something is oxidized, something is reduced, so what is being reduced?

It's $\ce{Cu2O}$ - Cu(I) not (II)... and this is a Q&A site, not a forum.

The copper in Fehling's solution has a +2 oxidation state, while it has a +1 oxidation state in the red precipitate, $\ce{Cu2O}$. This is the reduction half reaction. The oxidation half reaction turns the aldehyde into a carboxylic acid.
